# Schematics: If I turn off light in room 1 the light in room 2 turns on and vice versa?

Tags: led, schematics, lamp

I need something like this:
If I turn off light in room 1 the light in room 2 will turn on and vice versa (if I turn off light in room 2 the light in room 1 will turn on). Also I don't know how can I then turn off both lights (maybe add some extra switches for that?). How will look like schematics of this using only power source, lamps (or leds) and switches?

Comment: wont that waste electricity ;)

Comment: With only 1 selector in each room ?  using logic levels and LVDC LEDs?  including shut off both rooms?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Yes with 1 selector in each room (but I don't mind more selectors) and including shut off both rooms. Possibly with lamps instead of LVDC LEDs.

Comment: Your new requirement, a shutoff in each room, will really mess this up. It means that to get any light on you may have to visit both rooms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fA7hF0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A solution using using only switches.*

Switch 1 is a single-pole, double-throw switch.

Switch 2 is a double-pole, double-throw switch.

Switch 3 is a single-pole, single-throw (regular) switch and will turn off both lights.

Comment: Perhaps you should note that SW2 is called a "four-way switch" in the lighting industry (if my brain didn't just fuzz over) and is pre-wired just the way you have shown it (in short, it's not a true DPDT switch but is a custom wired one, instead.) The SPDT is called a "three-way switch," too.

Comment: "*The SPDT is called a "three-way switch," too.*" Only on your side of the Atlantic, Jonk. The switch has only two ways - up or down. It *does* have three terminals. If I had to guess what a four-way switch meant over there I would expect it to be an intermediate or cross-over switch to add a third switch to an upstairs-downstairs switch circuit. (The switch in the middle has to swap the two lines passing through it.)

Comment: Well, your sun rises too early, too. You should fix both those problems. ;) --- The four-way here is exactly as you've diagrammed the DPDT, if you include the two jumpers so that the result only has four screw terminals remaining to tie into. Probably got that name because of the four separate tabs. (SPST = 2 way, SPDT = 3 way, and cross-wired DPDT = 4 way.) "way" = number of terminals, I guess, over here.